# Draw.io Uncaught TypeError: dialog.showSaveDialogSync is not a function

Tags: exception, drawing, draw

When trying to save or do any operations in Draw.io, I am getting bellow error,

> Uncaught TypeError: dialog.showSaveDialogSync is not a function

[image]

**How to get rid of this?**

Comment: Update to the latest version https://github.com/jgraph/drawio-desktop/releases

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updating the app to the latest version from [here](https://github.com/jgraph/drawio-desktop/releases) resolved the issue.

Comment: I'm using linux and got the same error. Did the update and it worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me (draw.io version13.01) when I was using a filename that had special characters (spaces, brackets). For example using a shape library with special characters in the name. This probably happens because draw.io has a UNIX background.

You can rename the file and reopen it or for a shapes library, export the library using a 'normal' filename' and reimport it.